# Do I always need to escape metacharacters in a string that is not a "literal"?

Tags: java, regex, string

It seems that having a string that contains the characters `{` or `}` is rejected during regex processing. I can understand that these are reserved characters and I need to escape them so if I do:

```
string.replaceAll("\\" + pattern);
```

This works, where `pattern` is any string starting with `{`.

**Question:** Is there a way to avoid such problems with strings that already contain such metachars so that it is handled automatically? Seems to me it should be the same as adding a double quote in a string literal vs accepting a string as input that already has the double quote

Comment: use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`.

Comment: @Pshemo:They behave differently?

Comment: Read documentation... There is `replace(char, char)` and `replace(String, String)` both should work for you.

Comment: If any of the answer have helped you please accept it to point out the correct solution!

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Pattern.quote(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-):

> ```
> public static String quote(String s)
> ```
>
> Returns a literal pattern `String` for the specified `String`.
>
> This method produces a `String` that can be used to create a `Pattern` that would match the string `s` as if it were a literal pattern.
>
> Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.
>
> **Parameters:**
>       `s` - The string to be literalized
>   **Returns:**
>       A literal string replacement
>   **Since:**
>       1.5

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(java.lang.String)
```

to escape meta characters used by regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

- if you need regex syntax use `replaceAll` or `replaceFirst`,
- if you want your `target/replacement` pair to be treated as literals use `replace` (it also replaces ***all*** occurrences of your target).

---

Most people are confused by unfortunate naming of replacing methods in String class which are:

- `replaceAll(String, String)`
- `replaceFirst(String, String)`
- `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`
- `replace(char, char)`

Since `replaceAll` method explicitly claims that it replaces *all* posible targets, people assume that `replace` method doesn't doesn't guarantee such behaviour since it doesn't contain `All` suffix.
***But this assumption is wrong.***

Main difference between these methods is shown in this table:

```
╔═════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                     ║                             replaced targets                      ║
║                     ╠════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╣
║                     ║           ALL found                ║      ONLY FIRST found        ║
╠══════╦══════════════╬════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║      ║   supported  ║ replaceAll(String, String)         ║ replaceFirst(String, String) ║
║regex ╠══════════════╬════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║syntax║      not     ║ replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)║              \/              ║
║      ║   supported  ║ replace(char, char)                ║              /\              ║
╚══════╩══════════════╩════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```

Now if you don't need to use regex syntax use method which doesn't expect it, but it treats `target` and `replacement` as literals.

So instead of  `replaceAll(regex, replacement)`

use `replace(literal, replacement)`.

---

As you see there are two overloaded versions of `replace`. They both should work for you since they don't support regex syntax. Main difference between them is that:

- `replace(char target, char replacement)` simply creates new string and fill it either with character from original string, or character you decided as replacement (depending if it was equal to target character)
- `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` is essentially equivalent of 
  `replaceAll(Pattern.quote(target), Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString())` which means that it is same as `replaceAll` but (which means it internally uses regex engine) but ***it escapes regex metacharacters used in `target` and `replacement` for us automatically***

Comment: @downvoter care to mention what is wrong with this answer so I could improve it?

Comment: Nice information, what materials will you recommend me if I want to learn java regex in depth? :)

Comment: @Muhammad http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html is best tutorial I found so far about pure regex and most of its flavours implemented in different languages. Java regex tutorial is also nice https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ but you should also read documentation of Pattern class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html which contains a lot of informations about what regex mechanisms are supported in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any extra code, just the `\Q` and `\E` constructs, as documented in [Java's Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

For example, in the following code:

```
String foobar = "crazyPassword=f()ob@r{}+";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\Q" + foobar "\\E");
```

the pattern would compile and foobar's special characters would not be interpreted as regex characters. See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/hE5aZ0/1).

The only thing that it won't match is where the input contains a literal `\E`. If you need to solve that problem too, just let me know in a comment and I'll edit to add that.