# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition

Tags: java, regex

I am parsing many txt files with regex engine in Java; while nothing happened with many txt files, with one following exception arise:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: 
Illegal repetition near index 1
b {en}http //fas org/sgp/crs/nuke/rs22542 pdf
```

The matching pattern is obtained looping on a set of strings computed at runtime, and the program is removing each matched pattern from text with `replaceAll()` but fails when pattern is non ordinary string `b {en}http //fas org/sgp/crs/nuke/rs22542 pdf`.

What does it mean? How can I fix it or let compiler ignore this error?

Comment: You haven't shown us your code, so it's hard to say what the specific problem is.

Comment: Apply `Pattern.quote()` to the pattern part that you want to match literally.

Comment: `{n}` is used in regex to represent repetition like `a{3}` will match `aaa`. regex is probably trying to inform you that `en` in `{en}` is incorrect value. I can't help you with proper solution if I don't know what you are trying to accomplish and what your code looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replaceAll` is using regex syntax and in regex `{n}` has special meaning which is repetition like `a{3}` represents `aaa`.

If you want to simply replace string literals use `replace` method instead of `replaceAll`.
`replace` is as basically `replaceAll` but without regex syntax (it adds escaping of regex mechanisms automatically).

You can find more informations in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33444647/1393766