# how to change String to Array and replace all punctuation marks

Tags: java, arrays, string

i have a String and i want change it to Array next show only split words in one line.
I have not idea how to do it my only idea is to do this like that :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ciag="Hello My name is Tomek, i am from Mars.";
    ciag=ciag.replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll(".", "");
    System.out.println(ciag);
```

but it is wrong too
any advice's

Comment: [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) accepts a regex, `.` matches everything in your string. Use `replace` instead.

Comment: People from Mars should already know that.

Comment: Advise: read the javadoc for the functions you are calling **carefully**. Typically **everything** you ever need to know about them is already written down there. Yes, asking questions here is fun ... but reading javadoc is more efficient. And being downvoted for not doing prior research isn't real fun anyway I guess.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33444647/1393766

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work.

```
String ciag="Hello My name is Tomek, i am from Mars.";
ciag=ciag.replace(",", "").replace(".", "");
System.out.println(ciag);
String[] arr = ciag.split("\\s+");
```

`replaceAll()` uses RegEx to replace and in RegEx `.` stands for any character. Use `replace()`.

`split()` also takes a RegEx and `\s+` matches one or more occurrences of a whitespace.

Comment: @cricket_007 Updating.

Comment: You could also keep the replaceAll. `[,.]` would work

Answer (score 2):

```
String ciag="Hello My name is Tomek, i am from Mars.";
String[] words = ciag.replaceAll("[,.]", "").split("\\s+");
```

Testing:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(words).toString());
```

Output:

```
[Hello, My, name, is, Tomek, i, am, from, Mars]
```

Explanation:

`[,.]` Is a regular expression. The `[]` is a character class, meaning that the regex will match any character inside the brackets. So `[,.]` means match a comma or a full stop. Any match for this character class will be replaced with an empty String `replaceAll("[,.]", "")`, so as a result of this, all commas and full stops are removed.

After the replacing is completed, we then split the resulting String with another regular expression `\\s+` which matches one or more whitespace. So `split("\\s+")` will split the String into words.

Comment: but the output is different i dont need bracket and comma

Comment: @TomaszPiotrowski that is just how the output looks when you run `Arrays.asList(String[]).toString()` Because it is a String[] not a String...

Comment: or i cant place this in correct place

Comment: @TomaszPiotrowski What do you mean it doesn't work? It works perfectly for the specification of your question.

Comment: its all ok i think my mistake